# AngularJS: How to listen to <input ng-change> when value is changed with a Slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Problem:**
Running into an issue where I'm trying to use `ng-change` on a text field. The snag is I'm using a slider to change a value of this text field.

The ng-change event works when I click into the text field and start typing: `logOutValue()` fires and logs out in my browser.

---

**The HTML:**

I'm using this Angular [range slider](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider)
 —> [(Example)](http://embed.plnkr.co/53AUdB/preview)

`<div ng-repeat='obj in testObjects'>
  <rzslider rz-slider-model="obj.max">
  <form>
   <input value='{{ obj.max }}' ng-change='logOutValue(obj)' ng-model="testObjects[obj.name]">
  </form>
 </div>`

The slider fills in the text input's value via `obj.max`. This works.  Again, when clicking in text field and typing, the value is logged out.

---

**In Controller:**

`testObjects = {};
  $scope.logOutValue = function(obj){
   console.dir(obj);
  };`

**Other ideas**
I tried to use a $watch but that only also seems to fire when textbox is clicked on and typed into.

`$scope.$watch('testObj', function(){
    console.log('this is working?');
  }, true);`

Comment: hi.. did u get ant solution?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch the change in the model binded to change event externally.. the only option we have is to use $watch..

here it looks like you have added $watch to wrong varible as "testObj" is not binded as the model to the input field.

please see video to understand difference between ng-change and $watch

```
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-the-ngchange-directive-in-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideEnded` event as described [here](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider#slider-events):  to be notified about model changes.